# AJAX call not working for php using visual studio code

Tags: php, html, ajax, server, web-applications

I am beginner in Web Development. I am building website for my business. Even after going through lot o questions my AJAX call is still not working. Please help me with this here's my simple html and php which I am trying just for demo purpose. I am suspecting system setup issues but cannot rectify so far.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <input type = "button" onclick = "testName()" value = "Display">  

</body>
</html>
<script>

    function testName(){

    var $name1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
    
        $.ajax({ url: '/welcome.php',
            data: {action: 'test'},
            type: 'post',
            success:function(result)
            {
            alert('Successfully called');
            },
            error:function(exception){alert('Exception:'+exception);}
        });
        }


</script>
```

Here is my simple php:

```
<?php
   echo 'Name received';
?>
```

I am getting following output:

[image]

Here's console error message from browser:
[image]

Comment: Can you narrow down "Not working" please?

Comment: My code is not giving success it is giving Error. basically php is not getting called.

Comment: _Which_ error is it giving? Please post the _complete_ error message

Comment: Added the Output.

Comment: You need to json encode the output so you don't get "object object" and can see what it actually says

Comment: Or just use your browser's network toll and console to see what's going on - its unclear why you don't appear to have done that already

Comment: I tried it. I am getting Exception as "Error" and jqxhr.status==0.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. There is issue with browser probably. I have added console output from browser.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you are not using a proper webserver to serve your page, hence you cannot make AJAX requests for security reasons. You need to use something like Apache or IIS on your machine to run your code - also, even if the AJAX was allowed, PHP would not execute without a webserver to execute it. I'm surprised this wasn't covered if you've done any introductory PHP courses or tutorials,  or bought a book about it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not setup to run PHP on your local machine. To verify this, if you navigate to welcome.php in your browser, do you see a page that just says,

```
Name received
```

(without the rest of the PHP code showing)? Or do you see:

```
<?php
   echo 'Name received';
?>
```

If you're seeing the latter, with all of the code showing, I'd recommend you Google/YouTube "how to run PHP on...". You can also checkout XAMPP or WAMP to get that setup locally on Windows or MAMP on Mac to get started.